# How to loop over a directory supplied via argument in batch?

Tags: loops, batch-file

I would like to loop through a directory (supplied by argument 1) and print the contents of the directory (I am using echo as a test; I will be using each file as an input for a command later on).

I want to run the command:

```
./script.bat C:/Foo/
```

Which will trigger the following (the for loop is where the help is needed)

```
@echo off

set arg1=%1
shift

cd /d %arg1%
for %%i in (*.*) do @echo %%i
```

Then list all of the files in the `C:\Foo` directory

Is this the best way of doing this? I would prefer to remove the `cd` call and have the loop iterate over `%arg1`, but I am not sure this is the batch way (I am a bash guy).

Comment: If you just want to list the contents of the directory just use the `DIR` command with the command line argument. `dir /a-d /b "%~1\*.*"`. Remember that Windows uses back slashes for path separators.

Comment: I think this is getting there for me `for /f %%i in ('dir /b %arg1%') do @echo %%i`, but I only get the file name. How can I get the full path?

Comment: Type `for /?` to see how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else is looking for this, I was able to achieve what I wanted by

```
for /f %%i in ('dir /s/b %arg1%') do @echo %%i
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading between the lines, how about

```
dir /s/b /a-d %*
```

where `/a-d` ignores directorynames.